# How to set image width to that of bootstrap column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This feels like a very simple problem that I am brain farting on.  I have 3 images that I would like to display a certain way.  Basically I want one image to fit a col-md/sm/xs-7 and 2 images to stack on top one another autofitting to col-md/sm/xs-3.  All wrapped between a col-md/sm/xs-1 on either side.

I cannot figure out what CSS I need to tell the image to resize to that of the column.  Any ideas?

Comment: width:100%; height:auto; on the child (the images) will fill 100% of the parent (the columns) assuming you have no margin applied to the child or padding applied to the parent. If you want the images to stack, then make sure you have display:block; set on each of the images.

Comment: Can you post your code or a minimal example?

Comment: Are the images at the correct dimensions? I mean the one that should be 50px by 100px has a ratio of `1:2` and the images that should be 50px by 50px are `1:1`? If not, how do you want to make them fit? Resize and distort the image or clip them?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <image class="img-responsive" src="largeimage.jpg" width="200" height="400"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="yourSmallImage.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <image class="img-responsive" src="yourSmallImage.jpg"  width="200" height="200"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't quite understand what exact way you are trying to arrange pictures but I think this should help you. If you paint me a picture of how you want the pictures arranged I'll tailor my answer to you.

Edit: Ok, I think I might(?) understand now and this is my solution. You'll have to either size the images the way you want. Or, hopefully they are already the size you want it and will fit nicely. Give this a try.

Comment: basically if the total space is 100px by 100px I want 1 image to stand at 50px by 100px and the second and third to fill 50px by 50px each stacked on top of one another

Comment: RhinoTekMN - then images must be square because the viewport is not. If they're not square they will be distorted or clipped as @KodosJohnson commented in the question.

Comment: That was just an example I want the image to fit whatever the size of the col size 7 is so if the col size 7 width is 300px then I want the image to fit 300px. This way no matter the viewport size the image will always 7/12 viewport wide the 2 other images will always be 3/12 viewport size stacked and there will be a 1/12 buffer on either side

Comment: @RhinoTekMN I understand that but you said the 7/12 image should be 100px tall and the 3/12 images should each be 50px tall. So one of them is taller and rectangular and the two images are square. Is this how it is currently?

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood. I think this is kind of what you wanted. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: KodosJohnson - Sorry I see what you are saying now.  I guess none of the images are originally square but then they are not 2:1 either the ratios of the original images are as follows.  col7 image 1.34:1 col3 top image 1.78:1 col3 bottom image 1.5:1 I should say some distortion is acceptable I believe that the col 3 images are close enough to where the distortion would be minimal on a standard viewport